# kvoop process on linux

Tags: linux

I am seeing a few `kvoop` process on `Linux` (Suse). What are these? Performance seem degraded as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are the the out-of-process helper for [Verity Keyview](http://www.autonomy.com/content/Products/idol-modules-connectors/index.en.html) a text extraction library (i.e. it can extract the plain text from PDF files, from Word files and many others).

Verity does not write the code to gracefully handle corrupted files.  Rather then checking the data is valid and giving up, often times it will just crash bringing down the process that is using it.  To deal with this, they offer an out-of-process mode so that when their code crashes, it doesn't bring down your code as well.

Answer (score 2):

Lotus Domino Server includes a process of that name.

If you examine `/proc/<pid>/exe` (where  is the process ID you're interested in), you can find the path of the executable, which should help you track it down.

This really belongs on ServerFault, though.

Answer (score 0):

2017 exe -  Docker uses it too.
The process as per my server appears as follows.

`/proc/20827/exe -> /usr/bin/docker-current`

This had me scratching my head for a long time and I had to eyeball the `top` output to find the `pid` as it does not show up always but it did on my simpler monitoring dashboard. It is very confusing when symlink names show up in process list. @caf answer reminded me of that particular trick to get the original name.